# Why is it so demanding to call setTimeout in a loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

TLDR:
When running the following JS code in Chrome (OSX):

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
}, i)}
```

I get a warning saying "[Violation] 'click' handler took 265ms".
Why is that?

Background:
I'm working on a music related app and one of the features we want to implement being able to play a measure in a loop for 1000 times (1000 being similar to 'infinite' in terms of the user's experience). If a measure has 4 notes, that requires me to setup 1000 * 4 timeouts which causes this massive performance issue. If the measure has 16th notes then my browser basically breaks down ^^

Cheers!

Edit: some suggested not using timers at all for timing Web Audio API - which is a very good advice :)
However, for my app we are also animating a cursor showing which notes are played which requires setTimeout

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout` for this? Use the [`Web Audio API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) and schedule the notes through that.

Comment: Another (and perhaps even bigger) problem here is that `setTimeout` doesn't actually guarantee precise timing.

Comment: (If you wanted “infinite”, then why is this using setTimeout, and not setInterval to begin with?)

Comment: Because your instantly creating 4000 timers, and timers are a resource.  You only need 1 timer to do what you need.

Comment: setInterval is even worse. If one wants to do setInterval, nothing prevents actually calling setTimeout within the interalee function.

Comment: @MT0 see edit - you are correct that timing the playback using Web Audio API doesn't require setTimeout. However I also need to time a cursor which shows which notes are played

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `AudioContext` and attach a callback function to the `onend` event for the OscillatorNode. If you want to also listen for the start of note then you can play a silent note beforehand and listen for it's end.

```js
context = new AudioContext();

function playNote(
  frequency,
  start_time,
  stop_time,
  start_callback,
  stop_callback
)
{
  silent = context.createOscillator();
  silent.frequency.setValueAtTime( 0, context.currentTime )
  silent.start(context.currentTime);
  silent.stop(context.currentTime + start_time );
  if ( start_callback )
  {
    silent.onended = start_callback;
  }
  
  osc = context.createOscillator();
  osc.connect(context.destination);
  osc.start(context.currentTime + start_time);
  osc.stop(context.currentTime + stop_time);
  osc.frequency.setValueAtTime( frequency, context.currentTime + start_time )
  if ( stop_callback )
  {
    osc.onended = stop_callback;
  }
}

function showStartedPlaying()
{
  this.classList.remove( "not_playing", false );
  this.classList.add( "playing", true );
}

function showStoppedPlaying()
{
  this.classList.remove( "playing", false );
  this.classList.add( "not_playing", true );
}

notes = {
  "A": { frequency: 440.00, element: document.getElementById( "note_a" ) },
  "B": { frequency: 493.88, element: document.getElementById( "note_b" ) },
  "C": { frequency: 523.25, element: document.getElementById( "note_c" ) },
  "D": { frequency: 587.33, element: document.getElementById( "note_d" ) },
}

playNote(
  notes["A"].frequency,
  0,
  1,
  showStartedPlaying.bind( notes["A"].element ),
  showStoppedPlaying.bind( notes["A"].element ),
)
playNote(
  notes["B"].frequency,
  1,
  2,
  showStartedPlaying.bind( notes["B"].element ),
  showStoppedPlaying.bind( notes["B"].element ),
)
playNote(
  notes["C"].frequency,
  2,
  3,
  showStartedPlaying.bind( notes["C"].element ),
  showStoppedPlaying.bind( notes["C"].element ),
)
playNote(
  notes["D"].frequency,
  3,
  4,
  showStartedPlaying.bind( notes["D"].element ),
  showStoppedPlaying.bind( notes["D"].element ),
)
```

```css
.note { display: inline-block; width: 2em; text-align: center; }
.not_playing { background-color: red; }
.playing { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<p id="note_a" class="note not_playing">A</p>
<p id="note_b" class="note not_playing">B</p>
<p id="note_c" class="note not_playing">C</p>
<p id="note_d" class="note not_playing">D</p>
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that piece of code helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [AudioScheduledSourceNode start method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/start), it schedules a sound to begin playback at the specified time. If no time is specified, then the sound begins playing immediately.

```
context = new AudioContext();
osc = context.createOscillator();
osc.connect(context.destination);

/* Schedule the start and stop times for the oscillator */

osc.start(context.currentTime + 2);
osc.stop(context.currentTime + 3);
```